# Quantum physics and separation fallacy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics

I'm deeply interested in understanding delayed choice eraser experiment. Although I understand the experimental results, the retro causality is causing a big headache.

From what I understand, the hidden variables theory is a no - no, due to experimental verification of the Bells inequality...

[A recent PDF that I came across](http://philosophyfaculty.ucsd.edu/faculty/wuthrich/philphys/EllermanDavid2012Man_QuantumEraser2.pdf)  confused me, hence this question...

The PDF claims that the superposed eigenstates will continue to evolve, if not interrupted by a detector.

My question is: Can it be established that it continues to evolve despite not being measured? Doesn't that violate the Copehagen interpretation -or- is it an understanding that is implicit to the quantum processes itself? Or am I making a noob mistake?

Comment: Are you sure it said that the eigenstates/observables continued to evolve, or the wavefunction? (The pdf doesn't load for me, so I can't check . )